# No interaction in a two-way ANOVA, only one main effect significant, do i need to do further analysis?

Tags: anova, t-test, interaction, post-hoc, reporting

In testing the influence of gender and frequency of internet use (high v low) on self-esteem, we found no interaction or difference between internet frequency; but a difference between gender.

Given that there are only two levels, do I skip the post-hoc tests? should I carry out an independant t-test for the gender/esteem ratings? or just report results as they are found within the initial analysis?

thank you

Comment: Low versus high internet usage is not as binary as biological sex, internet usage is time spent during an elapsed time, i.e., a real number fraction. When this is made binary, information is lost.

Comment: Did you apply Anova for results reported in First paragraph ? May also indicate precise objectives of your study/analysis. What is the type of scoring or levels  for self-esteem measure.